# iOS background task fails to run

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a background task whereby my app contacts an API endpoint every 15 minutes and if the response contains a certain value the background task will display a local notification. My app is never contacting the API endpoint, which leads me to believe the background task is never running.

The API is my own, and only supports http traffic right now. I have created an `info.plist` entry for `App Transport Security Settings` setting `Allow Arbitrary Loads` equal to `YES`.

I have also added a `Background Modes` configuration in `Signing & Capabilities` enabling `Background fetch` and added a `Permitted background task scheduler identifier` entry in my `info.plist`.

A minimal reproducible example follows. Note that I have swapped out the URL for my API with something free and public, so anyone should be able to run this without worrying about authentication or API keys. This MRE also fails, but I can't monitor the endpoint's traffic to see if my app has ever contacted it.

BackgroundAlertApp.swift:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        
        /*
         Access the user notification center and request permission to send notifications
         */
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { granted, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
        /*
         Define an action allowing the user to dismiss the air quality alert and add this action
         to an AirQualityNotification Category of notifications.
         */
        let dismissAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "DISMISS", title: "OK", options: [])
        let airQualityNotification = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "AIR_QUALITY", actions: [dismissAction], intentIdentifiers: [])
        center.setNotificationCategories([airQualityNotification])
        
        /*
         Register the background task responsible for scheduling API calls to check for an alert
         */
        BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.my_org.bundle_id.apiRequest", using: nil) { task in
            self.performApiRequest(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }

        scheduleApiRequest()

        return true
    }

    func scheduleApiRequest() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.my_org.bundle_id.apiRequest")
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 15 * 60)
        
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule API request: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func performApiRequest(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        scheduleApiRequest()
        
        let operation = ApiRequestOperation()
        let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
        
        task.expirationHandler = {
            operation.cancel()
        }
        
        operation.completionBlock = {
            task.setTaskCompleted(success: !operation.isCancelled)
        }
        
        operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
    }
}

class ApiRequestOperation: Operation, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    var apiResponse: Response?
    
    func requestAlert() {
        let api = URL(string: "https://api.agify.io/?name=john")
        let sesson = URLSession(configuration: .default)
        let task = sesson.dataTask(with: api!) { data, response, error in
            if error == nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                if let safeData = data {
                    do {
                        let results = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: safeData)
                        self.apiResponse = results
                        print(results)
                        if self.apiResponse!.name == "john" {
                            // show remote noticifaction as alert
                            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                            content.title = "Air Quality Alert"
                            content.body = "\(self.apiResponse!.name) is predicted to be \(self.apiResponse!.age) years old and has been searched \(self.apiResponse!.count) times."
                            content.categoryIdentifier = "AIR_QUALITY"
                            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
                            
                            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "AIR_QUALITY", content: content, trigger: nil)
                            
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(
        _ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
        didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void
    ) {
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

When writing this code I referenced the following Apple Documentation:

[Using Background tasks to update your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app)

[Asking Permission to Use Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications)

[Scheduling a Notification Locally from Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app)

Comment: "whereby my app contacts an API endpoint every 15 minutes" You can't. A background task runs when the device system wants, not when _you_ want. iOS has absolutely no provision for "do something every 15 minutes while the app is backgrounded". The only thing certain when the app is in the background is that it is _not_ running (with some fixed exceptions such as music players).

Comment: The solution for your use case isn't polling and then posting a local notification. As matt notes, that's impossible on iOS, by design. The solution you need is to push a remote notification from your server when there is new data. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app Alternately, you can use things like app refresh to update your app, but they will run when the OS decides to run them. Polling designs are not possible.